# Я вижу только белый экран при публикации проекта в браузере с GitHub Pages

Tags: github-pages

https://alexey-rgb.github.io/react-movies-app-1version/
Добрый день, перейдя по этой ссылке, вы увидите белый экран, но сначала была другая проблема, сначала отображался файл readme и я изменил местоположение index.html из папки в корень проекта с помощью npm run edject и затем я увидел белый экран. Также я могу сказать, что это creact-react-app и что на стадии разработки на моей локальной машине всё работает хорошо, но не со страницами GitHub.

Сегодня я использовал это руководство, https://github.com/gitname/react-gh-pages/tree/master, но результат такой же, белый экран

Вот такой лог https://pastenow.ru/9OVSA

[image: скриншот лога]

---

https://github.com/gitname/react-gh-pages/tree/master как раз в этом руководстве, на выходе код берётся не из master, а из ветки gh-pages и я достиг этого, но всё равно белый экран(правда руководство это приводил в действие на готовом проекте а не в начале, поэтому может быть что то с путями, но я не знаю как проще это выяснить, кажется нужно с нуля всё переписывать с учётом руководства). Когда про статический сайт говорится, то насколько я понимаю в документации речь идёт о том, что взаимодействие со сторонними сервисами не возможно

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я знаю, на github pages показываются статические сайты, соответственно, скриптов для сборки недостаточно, развёрнутая ветка должна содержать готовый скомпилированный код.

Comment: Там есть ветка gh-pages с готовым скомпилированным кодом, просто путь где-то неправильно прописан (ищу где)

Answer (score 1):

В моём случае изменил BrowserRouter на HashRouter и вся проблема решилась. Ветка gh-pages/ root

https://github.com/rafgraph/spa-github-pages также более подробно говориться тут.